# How to access the DOM of a Contentful page with a bookmarklet?

Tags: javascript, contentful

After a page like this is fully loaded
https://app.contentful.com/spaces/.../entries/...
(an internal customized company page for editing a page on a site), I easily can access elements and text like this from the console:

```
document.querySelectorAll("p[data-test-id='cf-ui-paragraph']")[8].textContent;
```

But using the same query in a bookmarklet fails on the very first line -- even after the page is fully loaded.

```
javascript:(function() {
    var path = document.querySelectorAll("p[data-test-id='cf-ui-paragraph']")[8].textContent;
    //
    //
})();

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'textContent')
```

This seems to be a common issue but all I've seen here is the fact that it's 'not the same DOM'.

Any wisdom on how to get this (or any query at all) working on a Contentful backend editor page?

Comment: So is it the same document or not? I can't tell because I don't have access to the page you linked

Comment: It's the same web page, yes. But the bookmarklet can't access the elements, whereas the console definitely can.

Comment: How did you open the console? If you used "inspect element" from the context menu, that might have opened the console in the context of an iframe or something - a different `document`.

Comment: I did use the context menu. So then I refreshed the page and opened the console using keyboard shortcuts. Now the query in the console code doesn't work. On the right track now! So how to determine which paragraph elements to target - if using inspect element just messes things up all over again? When I searched through the index numbers trying to find the element I was selecting previously, it wasn't there - even though it's visible on the page.

Comment: Figure out what (i)frame the contentful editor is using, then select that first in the top frame DOM, before accessing its [`contentDocument`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentDocument) (on which `.querySelectorAll("p[data-test-id='cf-ui-paragraph']")` should work)

Comment: document.querySelectorAll("iframe") gives me 3 nodes. All of them have a ContentDocument of null

Comment: No, find out what identifies the iframe you're looking for and write an appropriate selector. It probably has an id or class name, no?

Comment: I think I found it. First time I heard that using Inspect Element isn't the best way to do things. Seems like DevTools should have told me that the html and body elements I was seeing were nested in an iframe. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240546/discussion-between-dwilbank-and-bergi).